# Cannot define key for model using mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm attempting to set fields in a database using the mvc3 method. When I run the program I get a

> System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'CarModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

my model looks like this

```
public class CarModel
{

    public string VIN { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Mileage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen where people add a ID, but the database doesnt have an ID property. And when I attempt to add [Key] above the VIN, which is the primary key in the database. It gives an red squiggly error under key.

It seems im missing some reference.

Comment: What is the exact error message for the key attribute?

Comment: System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'CarModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: The EntitySet Cars is based on type CarModel that has no keys defined.

Comment: the type or namespace 'key' could not be found

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?  If EF 4.1, are you using DB first, Model first or Code first?

Comment: CTP 5, 4.1 would not work with accessing the database with pluralizing table names. The DB was created first and outside my control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reference you're missing is probably `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`; is this not added for you if you type *Ctrl-.* with the cursor next to `[Key]`?

Comment: that was exactly the reference I was missing. Thanks for your help. Nothing happens when I type ctrl-? should it

Comment: Ctrl-. (Ctrl and the period key) should give you a dialog which allows you to easily import types defined in particular namespaces.  The cursor must be next to the red underlined text.

Answer (score 3):

Entity framework requires each entity to have a Primary Key defined. If you just want to remove the error then add this:

```
[Key]
public int id { get; set; }
```

and

```
public CarModel()
{
    id = 1;
}
```

Comment: the [Key] doesnt work, its gives a red squiggly error saying "the type or namespace 'key' could not be found"

Comment: I had to build my project before the Key was recognized by my Add Controller command.

Comment: The DataAnnotations namespace is where the key attribute resides.